# Algebraic meaning of the roots of a polynomial in the context of linear algebra, specifically linear transformation

Tags: linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

A polynomial of order n $p(x) = \Sigma_{i=0}^n c_i x^i$ is isomorphic to $R^n$. So is there any algebraic meaning of the roots of a polynomial in the context of linear algebra, specifically linear transformation etc.?

Comment: If you fix the base $\{1,x,\ldots, x^n\}$ then you can obtain the coordinates of a polynomial $p(x)$ with respect to its roots (by using [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)) and $p(0)$

Comment: A polynomial cannot be "isomorphic" to a vector space. This doesn't make sense (in terms of definitions)